# Dimension of $\mathcal{C}(X)$ for a compact Haudorff space $X$ having at least $n$ points

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a non-empty compact Hausdorff space. If $X$ has at least $n$ points, can one say that the dimension of $\mathcal{C}(X)$, the space of continuous real functions over $X$ is at least $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the dimension of $C(Y)$ where $Y$ is an $n$-element subset of $X$
is precisely $n$. Note that $Y$ is closed in $X$. By Tietze's extension
theorem, each element of $C(Y)$ is the restriction of an element of $C(X)$.
Therefore $C(X)$ has dimension $\ge n$.